# Make Sweave or knitr put graphics suffix in `\includegraphics{}`

Tags: r, latex, sweave, knitr

I just run into the (curious) problem that when submitting a (pdf)LaTeX manuscript to some Elsevier journal the filenames of figures needed to be complete in order to found by their pdf building and checking syste, i.e.:

```
\includegraphics{picture.pdf}
```

Is there any easy and convenient way to tell Sweave or knitr to do that?

Edit:

- I'm familiar with sweave's `include=FALSE` option
- I also feel quite capable to patch `utils:::RweaveLatexRuncode`

However, for the moment I'm hoping that there's something more convenient and elegant.

It's also about handing out the .Rnw files as supplementary material or vignettes. From a didactic point of view I don't like these tweaks that make the source code much more complicated for the new users of whom I hope they read it.

(Which is also why I really appreciate the recently introduced `print=TRUE` in Sweave)

Comment: do you mean `print=TRUE` or `split=TRUE`?

Comment: @Yihui: I meant `print=TRUE` because then the grid (lattice,ggplot2) graphics commands in the Vignette look like you type them in. Just leaves the trap "why doesn't it work in a for loop"... But people don't wonder why the vignette has `print (xyplot (...))`.

Comment: I see. You probably already know that `knitr` does not require `print(xyplot(...))`.

Comment: I do :) but maybe others who look up the thread did not...

Comment: I don't! I got here by searching for a reason why `knitr` run from Rstudio wasn't displaying my `xyplot`s called inside for loops, haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the `plot` hook a little bit in `knitr` to add the file extension:

```
<<>>=
knit_hooks$set(plot = function(x, options) {
  x = paste(x, collapse = '.') # x is file.ext now instead of c(file, ext)
  paste0('\\end{kframe}', hook_plot_tex(x, options), '\\begin{kframe}')
})
@
```

See [033-file-extension.Rnw](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/033-file-extension.Rnw) for a complete example. To understand what is going on behind the scene, see the [source code of the default LaTeX hooks](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/R/hooks-latex.R) in `knitr`.

Comment: This one is going to be an important hook for me... Till now I stayed with with plain `Sweave` for everything I may share with others (`knit`ting stuff where I don't share the .Rnw) but I guess I'll switch completely to knitr sooner or later :-). Big thanks for the package, Yihui!

Answer (score 3):

A brute force solution is to explicitly create the files yourself in the R snippet. Set the option for graphics etc to false but have the code evaluated so that the file is created, and then have latex call them with the very `\includegraphics{}` call you show.

I used similar schemes for simple caching: if the target file exists, skip the code creating.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, I elaborated a bit on the reasons why I'd like to find a "nicer" solution. `<<include=FALSE>>=` is what I do...